# columnheader is not hiding - datatables

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

i use the colVis plugin.
all is fine. But when i click one of the checkboxes the Content of the table, which i have clicked,is hidding but the columnheader don´t.
Can you tell me what´s wrong

Tank u.

```
 @import "DataTables2/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css";
 @import "DataTables2/media/css/demo_table.css";
 @import "DataTables2/media/css/demo_page.css"; 
 @import "TableTools2/media/css/TableTools.css";
 @import "ColVis/css/dataTables.colVis.min.css";
 @import "FixedHeader/css/dataTables.fixedHeader.css";

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="jquery/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ColVis/js/dataTables.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="FixedHeader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.js"></script>


$(function(){    
oTable = $('#table').dataTable({
    "sDom": 'TC<"clear">lfrtip', 
    "bJQueryUI":true,
    "bRetrieve": true,

    "oColVis": {
         "aiExclude": [ 0 ],
         "restore": true,                      
         "activate": "mouseover",
                },
     (...)
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this in JQuery.

```
$('tableId').parents('datatableWrapperId').first().hide();
```

This will hide first element of Wrapper(Inside which datatable is there) of datatable (Say Division) so ultimately Whole table including headers will disappear.

*NOTE:Please add datatable to division for this code to work.*

Comment: Thanks but it dosen´t work :( When i delete the 'columnFilter' it works. But together, 'colVis' and 'columnFilter' the above Problem is comming up.